# How to get the request body from a react-native WebView component?

Tags: webview, react-native, uri

Is there a way to intercept the **request body** of an uri (beside the title, target, navigationType, etc.) from a **react-native WebView** component?

Submitting a form request from a WebView component would return this when `onShouldStartLoadWithRequest` is triggered:

[image]

when I need also the body of the current form submitted.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you finally get a solution for this problem?

Comment: @SunnyRGupta we didn’t manage to find a solution for retrieving the body element, but we found an algorithm that worked for our specific context. We were interested into the user’s email that was successfully logged in, and since the user was redirected to the account page immediately after login, we decided to extract from the WebView its account details, this way we could manage the login session in the app.

Comment: I understand. It's weird how we cannot extract basic info even in the webviews we instantiate. We might also end up `postMessage`-ing the required info from within the webview over the bridge.